# How to access local maven repository when building fabric chaincode with gradle inside docker?

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperldger-fabric-peer

I have an artifact with common functions of my project installed as a jar in the local mavel repository, lets call it common.jar. Now I want to use these functions in my fabric chaincode. I added the dependency in the gradle build file of the chaincode, Intellij can built the chaincode with no problems.
I now try to deploy the chaincode to the test-network of the fabric samples. I.e.

```
peer lifecycle chaincode install chaincode.tar.gz
```

This will spin up gradle inside the docker-container which is the fabric peer node. This gradle instance then tells me it cannot find my common.jar.
I suspect the gradle inside the docker container cannot access the local maven repo where the jar resides. I am quite unfamiliar with docker configurations and the fabric sample network config is huge. How can I make my local maven repo availiable inside the dockered peer?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways of handling 3rd party dependencies like this.
Some more applicable to a development context - keep this in mind when deploying into production.

1. Though this isn't specifically what you asked, one option is to publish the module to a repository. Applicable more in a production context.
2. You can create an 'uber-jar' or a set of JAR files and put these inside the chaincode package. It's NOT a requirement for the code to be actually built by the peer. In fact pre-building the code into one or more JARs is actaully better. You get more reproduceable consistent builds. Check this [reference](https://hyperledgendary.github.io/docs/goodpractice/java_chaincode_packaging.html) for details on how to do that
3. An option that we use when developing new versions of the chaincode library itself, is to publish your module to a repository that is within the chaincode directory itself. Then reference that in your build gradle. This is the [script](https://gist.github.com/jt-nti/cedafc334a68598fa8674644fd1ef1ad) we use for this. Should be possible to craft something similar here.